# How to organize this in a mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I have some items, each item has a category and a sub-category. What is the best way to organize this in mysql ?

Comment: show your current code, what you have tried, looks like you just want us to do it for you without any attempt.

Comment: I don`t have anything for now....

Comment: My first idea was to add two columns to each row, one for the cat and sub-cat, but I think this is not the most optimal way....

Comment: Try something, then tell everyone what you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: without any context, database type, purpose or data you're not going to get 'the best way' there are too many possibilities

Comment: I want to navigate trough the categories, to show only the items from a selected category or subcategory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
categories
-----------
id
title
description

subcategories
-------------
id
title
description
category_id

items
-----------
id (*i had misspelled id as 'if'. corrected it here)
title
description
subcategory_id
```

Comment: How will you store : Engineering-> Hardware-> DIY Tools

Comment: @Taz ; I hadn't considered this as it wasn't specified, but one might add 'child_id' to the subcategories table.

Answer (score 3):

Create a table

```
catID 
CategoryName 
ParentCategory ....any other fields
```

Parent Category column will store  the  catID of Parent category if any.
or

```
CategoryTable
catID
CategoryName

CategoryRel Table
----------------------------------
ID
catID
SubcatID
```

where catID and subCatID are the IDs from category table.

Comment: First example is just ok. It allows multiple levels and all is needed is just one table. The second is more complicated and not reasonable.

Comment: @s3v3n Yes second is complicated but some may say first is not normalized?

Comment: Using this how it`s possible to show each item from a main category ?

Comment: Assuming that you pick the first example your items table will also have a foreign field - the category id.
All first level categories will have parent=0
To select all items from category x, you just do a simple select on items table where category=x
First example indeed can have some problems when using multiple levels.

Answer (score 2):

First, you have a big decision to make.  Will you design your database so that there are only two levels of category?  Or will you allow for more than two levels in the future?

If you are willing to accept a permanent limit of category and sub-category, you can add two tables.  Categories will list the allowed categories.  Subcategories will list the allowed Subcategories and what Category they belong to.  And your data table will include only the Subcategory. (If there is no information about a category other than its name, you could dispense with the Categories table and just include the category name in the Subcategories table.)

If you want to allow any number of levels, you will have only a single Categories table.  Each row will have the category name and another column with the parent category.  Your data table will still include a single category column.